# How to use jmeter to measure transmission time between websocket sender and receiver

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I have implemented a relay server on top of WebSocket. Sender will send many small binary messages to the server and they are then relayed to all the connected clients.

What I am interested in is the time between sender send the message and the reader receives the message. Right now I have already setup the Test Plan with a thread group of 25 receivers and another group of 1 sender and they can receive and send the message respectively.

The aggregate report is considering the send message and read message as two different labels. How should I configure the Test Plan to record my desired time?

p.s. I am using this jmeter WebSocket sampler plugin
https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The aggregate report is considering the send message and read message
>   as two different labels.

Sure it is, because there are two separate thread groups, according to you.

You need to sync & order the sampler results somehow, so I see two ways here:

1) Write raw sampler results (simple writer, aggregate report & summary report are capable of doing that), then use external tool (say, a table processor, Excel or similar) to process them, do that simple math and show your desired timings.

Or streamline the results to the timeseries DB (e.g. Influx) with [Backend Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) and proceed from there - like, do the math and/or visualize (say, with Grafana)

2) Second option seems to be syncing Thread Groups to each other with [InterThreadCommunication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin.

But that seems trickier to me, and what's more, may influence the timing readings (depending on way you do it) so the results got twisted.

Thus I personally would prefer passive metrics readings and post-calculations upon them (which could be turned pretty much "live" too, if you want, with BackendListener+Influx+Grafana bundle, or similar)

Comment: For the first method, does it mean I have to use a raw TCP sampler to send the WebSocket messages,then there will be more raw data available and I can do my post-calculation?

Comment: Up to you, I believe it is kinda sampler-type-agnostic - that's more about the overall approach to tymesyncing.

 As for what kind of data gets written - that, again, generally isn't sampler specific: all samplers produces standardized output with particular parameters, so the listeners always have pretty much same stuff to be written.

And you can configure that, refer to this section, please: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#defaults